# How to make API HTTP Requests using xCode, specifically twitter?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, twitter

I have found something called alamofire, which allows for using any already existing web server, however, this is a little over my head.

I would like to make API GET requests to twitter where I can specify a radius, a location, and an optional keyword. I know I need to do OAUTH, and when I tried looking through twitter's API I wasn't able to come to any good conclusion on how to implement this.

Comment: Alamofire is a great tool for this

Answer (score 1):

I won't get into twitter because there should be lots of documentation on it, but I would learn how to use `NSURLSession` for your GET requests. Alomofire certainly is a great tool as indicated by all of the individuals who have starred it on github. It also is very heavy as part of your project if you're doing just a simple GET. I'd say don't be scared to use `NSURLSession`. There are numerous great blog posts written about how to use NSURLSession in swift. Here's one: https://grokswift.com/completion-handlers-in-swift/

Here's a great starting point:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in
    print(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: mind helping me find one of these guides, I looked around a bunch and can't find anything definitive.